# Tutorial for openCL and openMP--locations?

Tags: linux, opencl, openmp

I am looking for tutorials on openCL and openMP.  I didn't see a thread on this in past, not to say it's not there.

I'm going to be developing in linux with i7-740QM, and nvidia gtx 285M.

Google hasn't helped me out on this one.

Comment: There are some books on OpenCL and on OpenMP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. OpenCL: http://www.macresearch.org/opencl is a *very* well explained set of videos with slides and sample code. Unlike the URL could suggest, this is ***not***  **restricted to mac**. He starts from scratch assuming no knowledge of GPU programming and goes up to memory access optimizations. I recommend watching the whole podcast. His optimizations are GPU-specific though ; you didn't specify what device you want to use.
2. OpenMP is pretty straightforward. [This will get you started](http://www.slac.stanford.edu/comp/unix/farm/openmp.html) (and has more links on the bottom) and [this goes further](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/openMP/). These were on the first page of googling "OpenMP tutorial".

Note: in your next question, please specify the programming language you want to use or, if yo don't care, say so.

Comment: How'd I miss the openMP ones?  Yeash.

Comment: Happens. Have fun with these technologies :)